# Não consigo ocultar o SCM Music Player no Tumblr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou tentando ocultar o SCM Music Player e expandir o container principal para 100% (pois o player o reduziu um pouco na parte de baixo) no meu blog do Tumblr mas meu código não funciona.

O código Javascript:

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    $(function(){
        $('body').contents().find('iframe').contents().find('#contentW').css({top: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px;});
        $('body').contents().find('iframe').contents().find('#playerW').css({display: none;})
    });
}, 5000);
```

A estrutura da página já carregada (percebam que eu omiti algumas partes desnecessárias):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        // algumas tags do Tumblr
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe> // Iframe desnecessário gerado pelo SCM
            <html>
                <head>
                    // algumas tags do SCM
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="contentW" style="top: 0px; bottom: 25px; right: 0px;">
                        // O CONTAINER PRINCIPAL DO BLOG ESTÁ AQUI
                    </div>
                    <div id="playerW" style="top: auto; bottom: 0px; height: 25px;">
                        // O PLAYER QUE EU QUERO OCULTAR
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

O que há de errado?

Comment: Tente fazer algo direto: `$("playerW").css("display", "none!important");`. Duas dúvidas referente à sua pergunta: 1 - Por que usar Jquery? O Tumblr não permite modificar o CSS diretamente? 2 - Por que está fazendo isso dentro de um `setTimeout`, alguma razão especifica?

Comment: 1-) Sim, mas eu já tentei e não funciona (talvez porque esteja dentro de um iframe). 2-) Na verdade é pra esperar o site carregar totalmente antes de executar o código (sei que o correto é document.ready, mas eu só estava testando assim).

Comment: Mas vou testar esse código que você passou...

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente consegui (sem JS e JQuery). Criei um arquivo CSS, fiz upload dele pro Tumblr e usei o link como uma 'custom skin' no site do SCM.

Código CSS:

```
#playerW {display: none !important;}
#contentW {top: 0 !important; bottom: 0 !important; right: 0 !important;}
```

Comment: Bom que consegui assim, pois via JS não ia dar por violar regras de segurança CORS. Estava a fazer um exemplo para mostrar isso mesmo... fica aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/kh8e1bfj/